# How to Speed up Rowdatabound of Gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Am using Vs 2010 with C# , and am binding gridview with more columns.The Columns contains Child 
controls ,the child control is Dropdown list.Am using RowDataBound event for some conditions.So the gridview loading time is extending. it is possible to reduce the loading time of gridview.

Here is my aspx

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"   CssClass="normtxt"
                                     HeaderStyle-BackColor="#819FF7"  HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" EmptyDataText="No records found" 
                                     OnRowCancelingEdit="gvDetails_RowCancelingEdit"  HeaderStyle-Height="30px"
                                     OnRowDeleting="gvDetails_RowDeleting" OnRowDataBound="gvDetails_RowDataBound"
                                    OnRowEditing="gvDetails_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="gvDetails_RowUpdating" OnRowCommand="gvDetails_RowCommand">
                                     <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066"  />
                                       <HeaderStyle BackColor="#7BA1C3" Font-Bold="false" ForeColor="White"  />
                                    <Columns>
                                      <%--  <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="40px">
                                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" Text="All"   AutoPostBack="true"
                                                    OnCheckedChanged="chkAll_OnCheckedChanged" />
                                            </HeaderTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkOne" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkAll_OnCheckedChanged"  />
                                            </ItemTemplate>

                                        </asp:TemplateField>--%>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ParagraphStyle" ItemStyle-Width="150" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblParagraphStyle" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ParagraphStyle") %>' />
                                              <%--  <asp:TextBox ID="txtParagraphStyle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ParagraphStyle") %>'
                                                    Visible="false" ></asp:TextBox>--%>
                                               <%-- <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" ServiceMethod="AutoCompleteAjaxParaRequest"
                                                    ServicePath="Service1.asmx" MinimumPrefixLength="1" CompletionInterval="100"
                                                    EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="10" TargetControlID="txtParagraphStyle"
                                                    FirstRowSelected="true" ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true">
                                                </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>--%>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Parent" ItemStyle-Width="150" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblParent" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Parent") %>'></asp:Label>

                                               <%-- <asp:TextBox ID="txtParent" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Parent") %>' Visible="false"  />--%>
                                                <%--<asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender2" runat="server" ServiceMethod="AutoCompleteAjaxParentRequest"
                                                    ServicePath="Service1.asmx" MinimumPrefixLength="1" CompletionInterval="100"
                                                    EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="10" TargetControlID="txtParent" FirstRowSelected="true"
                                                    ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true">
                                                </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>--%>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="fnCriteria" ItemStyle-Width="150" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                               <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlfnCriteria" runat="server"  Width="150px"  AutoPostBack="true" class="chzn-select"   onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"  />
                                               <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnfncriteria" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("fncriteria") %>' />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="fnCase" ItemStyle-Width="10" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                               <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlfnCase" runat="server"  Width="150px"  AutoPostBack="true" class="chzn-select"  onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" >                                                     
                                               </asp:DropDownList>
                                               <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnfncase" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("fnCase") %>' />

                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="fnFormat" ItemStyle-Width="150" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                               <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlfnFormat" runat="server"  Width="150px"  AutoPostBack="true" class="chzn-select"  onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>                                                   

                                               <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnfnFormat" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("fnFormat") %>' />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="fnDelete" ItemStyle-Width="150" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                               <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlfnDelete" runat="server"  Width="150px"  AutoPostBack="true" class="chzn-select"  onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" >                                                     
                                               </asp:DropDownList>
                                               <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnfnDelete" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("fnDelete") %>' />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="fnInsert" ItemStyle-Width="150" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                               <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlfnInsert" runat="server"  Width="150px"  AutoPostBack="true" class="chzn-select"  onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" >                                                     
                                               </asp:DropDownList>
                                               <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnfnInsert" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("fnInsert") %>' />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="fnTruncate" ItemStyle-Width="150" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblfnTruncate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("fnTruncate") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtfnTruncate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("fnTruncate") %>' Visible="false"  />
                                                <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender8" runat="server" ServiceMethod="AutoCompleteAjaxfnTruncateRequest"
                                                    ServicePath="Service1.asmx" MinimumPrefixLength="1" CompletionInterval="100"
                                                    EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="10" TargetControlID="txtfnTruncate"
                                                    FirstRowSelected="true" ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true">
                                                </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="fnOrder" ItemStyle-Width="150" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblfnOrder" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("fnOrder") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtfnOrder" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("fnOrder") %>' Visible="false"  />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Execution_Order" ItemStyle-Width="150" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblExecution_Order" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Execution_Order") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtExecution_Order" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Execution_Order") %>'   Visible="false" />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
```

and my code behind is

```
 protected void gvDetails_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            try
            {
                //Find the DropDownList in the Row
                DropDownList ddlfncriteria = (e.Row.FindControl("ddlfnCriteria") as DropDownList);
                HiddenField hdnfncriteria = (e.Row.FindControl("hdnfncriteria") as HiddenField);
                HiddenField hdnfncase = (e.Row.FindControl("hdnfncase") as HiddenField);
                DropDownList ddlfnCase = (e.Row.FindControl("ddlfnCase") as DropDownList);
                DropDownList ddlfnFormat = (e.Row.FindControl("ddlfnFormat") as DropDownList);
                HiddenField hdnfnFormat = (e.Row.FindControl("hdnfnFormat") as HiddenField);
                DropDownList ddlfnDelete = (e.Row.FindControl("ddlfnDelete") as DropDownList);
                HiddenField hdnfnDelete = (e.Row.FindControl("hdnfnDelete") as HiddenField);
                DropDownList ddlfnInsert = (e.Row.FindControl("ddlfnInsert") as DropDownList);
                HiddenField hdnfnInsert = (e.Row.FindControl("hdnfnInsert") as HiddenField);

                ddlfncriteria.DataSource = clsCommon.ExecuteQuery("select '--Select--' as fnCriteria union select distinct  fnCriteria from customizeFunction_test_from_frontend where fnCriteria <> '' ", "fncrt");
                ddlfncriteria.DataTextField = "fnCriteria";
                ddlfncriteria.DataValueField = "fnCriteria";
                if (hdnfncriteria.Value != "")
                {
                    ddlfncriteria.SelectedValue = hdnfncriteria.Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    ddlfncriteria.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }
                ddlfncriteria.DataBind();

                List<string> dd2 = new List<string>();
                dd2.Add("--Select--");
                dd2.Add("Lower case");
                dd2.Add("Upper case");
                dd2.Add("Title case");
                dd2.Add("Sentence case");
                ddlfnCase.DataSource = dd2;

                if (hdnfncase.Value == "0")
                {
                    ddlfnCase.SelectedIndex = 1;
                }
                else if (hdnfncase.Value == "1")
                {
                    ddlfnCase.SelectedIndex = 2;
                }
                else if (hdnfncase.Value == "2")
                {
                    ddlfnCase.SelectedIndex = 3;
                }
                else if (hdnfncase.Value == "4")
                {
                    ddlfnCase.SelectedIndex = 5;
                }

                ddlfnCase.DataBind();

                ddlfnFormat.DataSource = clsCommon.ExecuteQuery(" select '--Select--' as fnFormat union select  distinct  fnFormat from customizeFunction_test_from_frontend where fnFormat <> '' ", "fnformt");

                ddlfnFormat.DataTextField = "fnFormat";
                ddlfnFormat.DataValueField = "fnFormat";

                if (hdnfnFormat.Value != "")
                {
                    ddlfnFormat.SelectedValue = hdnfnFormat.Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    ddlfnFormat.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }
                ddlfnFormat.DataBind();

                ddlfnDelete.DataSource = clsCommon.ExecuteQuery("  select '--Select--' as fnDelete union all select  distinct  fnDelete from customizeFunction_test_from_frontend where fnDelete <> '' ", "fnformt");

                ddlfnDelete.DataTextField = "fnDelete";
                ddlfnDelete.DataValueField = "fnDelete";

                if (hdnfnDelete.Value != "")
                {
                    ddlfnDelete.SelectedValue = hdnfnDelete.Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    ddlfnDelete.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }
                ddlfnDelete.DataBind();


                ddlfnInsert.DataSource = clsCommon.ExecuteQuery("  select '--Select--' as fnInsert union all select  distinct  fnInsert from customizeFunction_test_from_frontend where fnInsert <> '' ", "fnformt");

                ddlfnInsert.DataTextField = "fnInsert";
                ddlfnInsert.DataValueField = "fnInsert";

                if (hdnfnInsert.Value != "")
                {
                    ddlfnInsert.SelectedValue = hdnfnInsert.Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    ddlfnInsert.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }
                ddlfnInsert.DataBind();

                //ddlfncriteria.DataSource = dd2;           
                //ddlfncriteria.DataBind();


                //Add Default Item in the DropDownList
                //ddlfncriteria.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select"));

                //Select the Country of Customer in DropDownList
                // string country = (e.Row.FindControl("lblCountry") as Label).Text;
                // ddlfncriteria.Items.FindByValue(country).Selected = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Suggest me to get a solution.

Comment: instead of GridView use repeater to speed up

Comment: and You have to optimize your work on `RowDataBound`